# Universal WinJS app - Accent Color

Tags: javascript, winjs

I am building an application in WinJS for Universal Windows applications.

Is there a way to find the user's current system-accent color, and use it in my application?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I found nothing on the Internet. Highlight is blue for me too and via JavaScript I found nothing :\

Comment: @kaiserkiwi nope, didn't find anything :(

Comment: I opened an own thread and got an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271638/how-to-get-the-system-accent-color-for-uwp-apps 
I tested it and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for the same thing - making a universal javascript app with HTML and CSS and I found my solution:

```
body {
    background-color: Highlight;
}
```

This 'color' is actually the hidden accent you're looking for, just put 'Highlight' anywhere you want the accent color to show.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried that, but the colour remained as blue even if I changed the accent.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you mean but - running it on "Local machine" does the same thing for me (perhaps because it doesn't really use the computer's accent) but when I open in in a phone emulator and change the phone accent in setting, the color changes no problem.

Does the color stay the same even after you build/deploy your app, or only while running it on "Local machine"?

Comment: I haven't tried it by building or deploying it yet. Thanks for the information though, definitely helpful :)