# How to get the system accent color for UWP-Apps?

Tags: css, windows-10, winjs, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to get the Accent Color of a user in a UWP-App for Windows 10. I know how to get it in C#, but I develop my apps in WinJS. So does anyone knows the WinJS equivalent for `var color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"];`?

It would also be nice, if I could Access this Color with CSS. I found some hints, that `color: Highlight;` would be the solution, but this gives me only a blue and not the Accent Color.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Self Quote: »It would also be nice, if I could Access this Color with CSS. I found some hints, that color: Highlight; would be the solution, but this gives me only a blue and not the Accent Color.«

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use WinRT API to do that : Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType enumeration provides all accents colors. You can make something like :

```
var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
var rgba = uiSettings.getColorValue(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.accent);
var cssColorString = "rgba(" + rgba.r + "," + rgba.g + "," + rgba.b + ", " + rgba.a + ")";
```

Comment: This helped for C# too, its almost exactly the same code.